# Approval Process - hiding certain processes depending on user

Tags: approval-process

Is there a way to hide certain approval processes depending on what kind of user you are? Every user will need to complete some sort of approval process but not all approval processes are relevant to the user.

[image: screenshot after hitting Submit For Approval]

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.

Comment: Does this Link help https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322175&type=1